# Ripple emulator is not working with Ionic on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, ripple

I am getting an error: `Error: static() root path required` when using the Ripple emulator with the Ionic Framework.

```
ripple emulate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get this to work, I added a path to the apps www folder its working perfectly now.

```
ripple emulate --path /Users/user/Desktop/app/www
```

More here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ripple-emulator